# I was creating endpoints in javalin and I tried to run but it gave me the message that " connection refused"

Tags: javalin

app.get("/firstname/{Kevin}", ctx -> {
ctx.result("Kevin");

```
    });

    return app;
}
```

}
i dont get my mistake

app.get("/firstname/{Kevin}", ctx -> {
ctx.result("Kevin");

```
    });

    return app;
}
```

}
i did this

Comment: Why are you doing `return app;` in each handler? Have you looked at the [documentation](https://javalin.io/documentation#endpoint-handlers)? Also, we don't know anything about `app` - how it is defined, for example.

Comment: You can provide a [mre].